# Handle Page Content when URL is /abc/1

Tags: 7

I want to handle the page content via a drupal module.

If the called URL is abc/[x] (for example abc/123, abc/456), then I want to render [x] on the page.

which is the best way in drupal to do this *without* views?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: are you using views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for the code to write in your own module, I would use the following one.

```
  function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/%'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
    );

    return $items;
  }

  function mymodule_abc_view($value = '') {
    print $value;
  }
```

If the page callback uses `print()`, then the outpage will contain just what the page callback prints; if the page callback returns that value, then the page will contain the value returned from the page callback, and any other thing output from Drupal, such as blocks.

If the number in the URL is an entity ID (for example, a node ID), then the code changes.
Supposing it's a node ID, then the code would be similar to the following one.

```
  function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['abc/%node'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_abc_view',
      'page arguments' => array(1),
    );

    return $items;
  }

  function mymodule_abc_view($node = NULL) {
    // Use $node to output something.
  }
```

#### References

- [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)
- [Dynamic argument replacement (wildcard)](http://drupal.org/node/109153)
- [Wildcard usage and core's wildcards](http://drupal.org/node/209056)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can accomplish this, here a few ideas;

- You could create custom templates based on the node ID of those
  pages...Examples here: http://drupal.org/node/1089656
- Also you could make use of the Context module:
  http://drupal.org/project/context
- You could also, create content in blocks, and set them to only show
  on the specified paths under the page visibility settings of any
  given block you create.